# Turn array of x,y coordinates in to a line (jpg) - Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am receiving a "signature" that has been drawn on a basic capture device, through an API call.

The response data from the device has a json object in it with the "signature", which I preparse in javascript and in turn pass to a python service which needs to store the captured signature, as a base64 encoded image (jpg preferably).

I could do the conversion in javascript (as per an answer given), if it must be there, but would prefer to do it in the python layer.

Here is an example of the data I am getting:

> { "data": [ { "x": "2B", "y": "58" }, { "x": "2D", "y": "5B" }, { "x": "2E", "y": "5E" }, { "x": "30", "y": "61" }, { "x": "30", "y": "63" }, { "x": "32", "y": "65" }, { "x": "33", "y": "67" }, { "x": "35", "y": "69" }, { "x": "36", "y": "6C" }, { "x": "38", "y": "6E" }, { "x": "3A", "y": "71" }, { "x": "3C", "y": "73" }, { "x": "3D", "y": "75" }, { "x": "41", "y": "79" }, { "x": "42", "y": "7B" }, { "x": "46", "y": "7F" }, { "x": "47", "y": "81" }, { "x": "49", "y": "83" }, { "x": "4D", "y": "89" }, { "x": "4F", "y": "8B" }, { "x": "52", "y": "8D" }, { "x": "54", "y": "8F" }, { "x": "57", "y": "90" }, { "x": "59", "y": "93" }, { "x": "5C", "y": "95" }, { "x": "61", "y": "9A" }, { "x": "63", "y": "9D" }, { "x": "66", "y": "9F" }, { "x": "69", "y": "A2" }, { "x": "72", "y": "A8" }, { "x": "74", "y": "AA" }, { "x": "77", "y": "AC" }, { "x": "79", "y": "AE" }, { "x": "7C", "y": "AF" }, { "x": "7E", "y": "B1" }, { "x": "80", "y": "B2" }, { "x": "82", "y": "B4" }, { "x": "85", "y": "B5" }, { "x": "87", "y": "B5" }, { "x": "89", "y": "B6" }, { "x": "90", "y": "B6" }, { "x": "95", "y": "B3" }, { "x": "97", "y": "B1" }, { "x": "99", "y": "AD" }, { "x": "9B", "y": "AC" }, { "x": "9D", "y": "A7" }, { "x": "9F", "y": "A4" }, { "x": "A2", "y": "9B" }, { "x": "A3", "y": "97" }, { "x": "A3", "y": "93" }, { "x": "A4", "y": "90" }, { "x": "A4", "y": "8C" }, { "x": "A5", "y": "87" }, { "x": "A5", "y": "77" }, { "x": "A6", "y": "73" }, { "x": "A6", "y": "67" }, { "x": "A7", "y": "63" }, { "x": "A7", "y": "60" }, { "x": "A9", "y": "5A" }, { "x": "A9", "y": "56" }, { "x": "AD", "y": "49" }, { "x": "AD", "y": "47" }, { "x": "AF", "y": "44" }, { "x": "B2", "y": "3A" }, { "x": "B3", "y": "36" }, { "x": "B6", "y": "2F" }, { "x": "BB", "y": "27" }, { "x": "BD", "y": "26" }, { "x": "BE", "y": "24" }, { "x": "C0", "y": "23" }, { "x": "C2", "y": "21" }, { "x": "C4", "y": "20" }, { "x": "C9", "y": "20" }, { "x": "FFFF", "y": "FFFF" }] }

Do I need to parse this to turn it in to a jpg, or is there a way I could use PIL (or another library) to turn this set of plots in to an image?

Comment: This looks like you are dealing with some kind of Hex color code. You have to convert the Hex color code into Binary or RGB format and it should work

Comment: @NiazPalak It's not a color code, those are hexadecimal x and y values describing a line

Comment: ow yeah my bad.. that makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote python or js in the title of the question, here is a js snippet which displays your json object in a `<canvas>` element.

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var json = '{ "signature": { "data": [ { "x": "2B", "y": "58" }, { "x": "2D", "y": "5B" }, { "x": "2E", "y": "5E" }, { "x": "30", "y": "61" }, { "x": "30", "y": "63" }, { "x": "32", "y": "65" }, { "x": "33", "y": "67" }, { "x": "35", "y": "69" }, { "x": "36", "y": "6C" }, { "x": "38", "y": "6E" }, { "x": "3A", "y": "71" }, { "x": "3C", "y": "73" }, { "x": "3D", "y": "75" }, { "x": "41", "y": "79" }, { "x": "42", "y": "7B" }, { "x": "46", "y": "7F" }, { "x": "47", "y": "81" }, { "x": "49", "y": "83" }, { "x": "4D", "y": "89" }, { "x": "4F", "y": "8B" }, { "x": "52", "y": "8D" }, { "x": "54", "y": "8F" }, { "x": "57", "y": "90" }, { "x": "59", "y": "93" }, { "x": "5C", "y": "95" }, { "x": "61", "y": "9A" }, { "x": "63", "y": "9D" }, { "x": "66", "y": "9F" }, { "x": "69", "y": "A2" }, { "x": "72", "y": "A8" }, { "x": "74", "y": "AA" }, { "x": "77", "y": "AC" }, { "x": "79", "y": "AE" }, { "x": "7C", "y": "AF" }, { "x": "7E", "y": "B1" }, { "x": "80", "y": "B2" }, { "x": "82", "y": "B4" }, { "x": "85", "y": "B5" }, { "x": "87", "y": "B5" }, { "x": "89", "y": "B6" }, { "x": "90", "y": "B6" }, { "x": "95", "y": "B3" }, { "x": "97", "y": "B1" }, { "x": "99", "y": "AD" }, { "x": "9B", "y": "AC" }, { "x": "9D", "y": "A7" }, { "x": "9F", "y": "A4" }, { "x": "A2", "y": "9B" }, { "x": "A3", "y": "97" }, { "x": "A3", "y": "93" }, { "x": "A4", "y": "90" }, { "x": "A4", "y": "8C" }, { "x": "A5", "y": "87" }, { "x": "A5", "y": "77" }, { "x": "A6", "y": "73" }, { "x": "A6", "y": "67" }, { "x": "A7", "y": "63" }, { "x": "A7", "y": "60" }, { "x": "A9", "y": "5A" }, { "x": "A9", "y": "56" }, { "x": "AD", "y": "49" }, { "x": "AD", "y": "47" }, { "x": "AF", "y": "44" }, { "x": "B2", "y": "3A" }, { "x": "B3", "y": "36" }, { "x": "B6", "y": "2F" }, { "x": "BB", "y": "27" }, { "x": "BD", "y": "26" }, { "x": "BE", "y": "24" }, { "x": "C0", "y": "23" }, { "x": "C2", "y": "21" }, { "x": "C4", "y": "20" }, { "x": "C9", "y": "20" }, { "x": "FFFF", "y": "FFFF" } ], "signature_format": "raw" } }';
    var signature = JSON.parse(json);
    var data = signature.signature.data;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(parseInt(data[0].x, 16), parseInt(data[0].y, 16));
    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
        ctx.lineTo(parseInt(data[i].x, 16), parseInt(data[i].y, 16));
    }
    
    ctx.stroke()
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Oh, this is a great starting point for me.  I guess you worked out the canvas size by using the fact that it is 2 char Hex.

Is this a standard format that you are aware of?

Is the FFFF just a terminating point?

Comment: @Richie I'm not aware of this being a standard format, however, I worked with a similar format in the context of gesture recognition. I think you are correct with FFFF being a terminating point (actually I didn't notice it being at the end when I wrote the code).